# 'Blend' in planes to create ocean/lake and also with Flip Fluids surface

Tags: rendering, objects, particles, edges, fluid-simulation

[image][image]
[image]

Hi there, normally I am able to find all the answers on this forum and it got me very far of what I want to realise. However, I wasnt able to find an answer to the following problem.

I created different planes and I want the edges to merge perfectly so it looks like one big plane. In the viewport they look good, but when I render them you see huge gaps (see picture). Initially I wanted to cover up the edges of my flip fluid surface, any tips about that would be very helpful because again huge gaps appear!

Let me know if any additional information is needed, thanks in advance!

Comment: First off, I cannot tell any difference between the outer planes and the inner ones. Is there?

Comment: please show a wire frame, or better share your blend file.

Comment: Here is some more information

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here but if it's to blend a flip fluids simulation with a plane with an ocean modifier there's an in depth tutorial on youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_aPHD9qe74&t=1s

Comment: You see the planes overlapping each other, which results in a dark blue area. This happens between plane 1 and 2 and also the flip fluid surface.

Comment: I just want those dark blue areas gone and have a smooth transition between the planes where it seems like one big plane